# Print the values of knapsack

Tags: c

solving the knapsack problem recursively, I want to know which items are taken in the bag that gives the maximum value. so far I have this:

I also tried to copy arr to another array to prevent overwriting but also didn't work!

```
int knapSack(int W, int wt[], int val[], int n, int arr[])
{
    int x, y, c, j, arr1[50], arr2[50];

    if (n == 0 || W == 0)
        return 0;

    // If weight of the nth item is more than Knapsack capacity W, then 
    // this item cannot be included in the optimal solution 
    if (wt[n - 1] > W)
    return knapSack(W, wt, val, n - 1, arr2);

    // Return the maximum of two cases:  
    // x nth item included  
    // y not included 
    arr1[n - 1] = val[n - 1];// I think this line isn't doing anything
    x = val[n - 1] + knapSack(W - wt[n - 1], wt, val, n - 1, arr1);
    //copyArr(arr, out, n);
    y = knapSack(W, wt, val, n - 1, arr2);

    if (x > y)
       c = x;
    else
        c = y;

    if (c == x)
        for (j = 0; j < 50; j++)
            arr[j] = arr1[j];

    else
        for (j = 0; j < 50; j++)
            arr[j] = arr2[j];

    return c;
}
```

Comment: There is no question in your question.

Comment: So what you are having problem with? There are solutions of [knapsack problem in C](https://www.thecrazyprogrammer.com/2016/10/knapsack-problem-c-using-dynamic-programming.html) already available online. Would you need someone to copy and paste the solution into stackoveflow? Why? What is your question?